# Don't understand part of this inductive proof of a divisibility property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

(Question 5, copied from here https://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/hw1sol.pdf)

Prove that for any **odd** number $m \ge 1$, the number $9$ divides $4^m+5^m$.

**Solution:** Every odd number $m$ can be written as $2n+1$, for some $n \ge 0$ (by the division theorem the remainder when dividing by $2$ is $1$ or $0$, and since $m$ is odd, it must be a remainder of $1$). We use induction on $n$ to prove the result. The base case is trivial since $4+5=9$ is divisible by $9$. Let us write $4^{2 n+1}+5^{2 n+1}=9 k$ for some $k \ge 1$. We shall show that $4^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)+1}$ is divisible by $9$. Indeed:

$$
\begin{aligned}
4^{2 n+3}+5^{2 n+3} &=16 \cdot 4^{2 n+1}+25 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}=16\left(4^{2 n+1}+5^{2 n+1}\right)+9 \cdot 5^{2 n+1} \\
&=16 \cdot 9 k+9 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}=9\left(16 k+5^{2 n+1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence, $4^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)+1}$ is also divisible by $9$. Hence, the induction step is proven, and by the Principle of Mathematical Induction, the property is true for all numbers $n \ge 1$, and so $4^m + 5^m$ is divisible by $9$ for all odd numbers $m \ge 1$.

**My question:** I don't understand how $16 \cdot 4^{2 n+1}+25 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}=16\left(4^{2 n+1}+5^{2 n+1}\right)+9 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}$. Where is the $9 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}$ coming from? Why is it $9 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}$ and not just $25$?

Comment: $16 \cdot 4^{2 n+1}+25 \cdot 5^{2 n+1}=16 \cdot 4^{2 n+1}+(16+9) \cdot 5^{2 n+1}$

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz